# changing constraints of object based on ipad or iphone

Tags: swift, iphone, if-statement, ipad, constraints

In my code to reach the desired effect i can only do it if I change the constraints based on whether the using a iphone or ipad. So i need to create something like if iphone constraints = and then if ipad constraints. I wrote a example of what I needed to do. I just need to change the the last line of the 4 statments controlling the bottom ancor.

```
     //ipad
     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        box.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25),
        box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.10),
        box.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        box.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

      ])

 //iphone
     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        box.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25),
        box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.10),
        box.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        box.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

      ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the size class. For ipads, the horizontal and vertical classes should both be regular. You could do something like the following:

```swift
    let horizontalSizeClass = view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass
    let verticalSizeClass = view.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass

    switch horizantalSizeClass {
    case .regular:
        // Do some layout.
    case .compact:
        // Make compact constraints...
    default:
        // Unspecified. Do something else.
    }
    
    // rest of setup
```

Also, the reason you couldn't make any constraints for was because you typed in `break` which ends the switch statement. The other answer might work.

Comment: can you give me a little bit more information? What is everything I call using this statement. I tried = true and that does not compile.

Comment: Use the view trait collection (`view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass`)!

Comment: I tweaked my answer. If you have any questions, feel free to comment them!

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the style of interface using `userInterfaceIdiom`:

```
switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
case .phone: break
// It's an iPhone
case .pad: break
// It's an iPad
default: break
// others
}
```